# nodemon Cannot find module '/path/to/project/home/index.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I'm using nodmeon `version 1.9.1` on a Linux machine.

I'm running nodemon with:  `nodemon --watch ./build` where I have my index.js content in the build folder.

But when I run nodemon it keeps looking for `index.js` file at the project's home folder hence it throws an error because it cannot find it there.

I tried to check nodemon --help for any better option but I don't see any and also wrote it in package.json file in scripts object it still throws the same error.

I've also tried to run it as `nodemon --watch ./build/index.js` still throws the error.

Also, the index.js file only contains a `console.log('hello world');` just to make sure, it's **nodemon** itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your use of `--watch` is throwing nodemon off.

What you're telling nodemon is "run normally, and watch the directory `./build`".  nodemon is looking for a parameter after `--watch` and finds `./build`.  It then looks for a script, finds none, and thus uses the default.

Nodemon watches by default so what you want to run is `nodemon ./build`

Comment: It worked, thank you. I took long to respond because something else went wrong, fixed it and it's great now. Thanks!